# 50% CPU usage on MySQL RDS instance (db.m3.medium) with 0 connections

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

We have a MySQL RDS instance which is still utilizing ~50% CPU after stopping our applications and terminating all connections (e.g. from MySQL workbench).

The mysql-error-running.log is showing:

```
2017-08-03T11:24:05.711179Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4813ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=5623 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2017-08-03T11:26:11.415416Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 11095ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=11538 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2017-08-03T11:33:07.901110Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 15667ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=15298 and evicted=0, during the time.)
2017-08-03T11:33:29.458855Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5004ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=4931 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

Can anyone advise on what is causing the persistent CPU usage here? Our applications have been disconnected from the RDS for over 40 minutes and CPU is still averaging 50% usage.

show process list is empty (aside from the connections used when connecting via MySQL workbench)

**UPDATE:** the RDS was rebooted and CPU dropped back down to expected levels.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason:

The "Change buffer" queues up index changes for eventual writing to disk.  If you did a lot of `INSERTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs` on table(s) with non-unique indexes, the CPU could have been busy for some time after the queries "finished".

The reboot may have only coincidentally cleared up the CPU.  The change-buffer work must be done eventually, even after a reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Looking at the cloud watch metrics, the CPU utilisation never returned to 50% following the reboot. It stays consistently around 11% (with the apps connected). The two major tables that are updated both have unique indexes.

Comment: `UNIQUE` indexes must be checked during the `INSERTs/UPDATEs/DELETEs`.  So the 'delayed' action of the Change Buffer is not relevant.